# Text and icon on the same line with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to get the text on the left side and the icon on the right side, but right now the icon is above the text, see the first image. I want the icon to be in the top right corner to the right of “Project name”, and the text to be like the second image.

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="flex card bg-neutral h-48 px-3 hover:bg-primary">
  <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M10 6H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h10a2 2 0 002-2v-4M14 4h6m0 0v6m0-6L10 14" />
  </svg>
  <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold text-white py-3">Project name</h2>
  <p class="text-left py-4 font-bold group-hover:bg-primary">Explaination of the project</p>
  <p class="text-left pb-4 font-bold">Tag, tag, tag</p>
</div>
```

[image: Result of code]

[image: Desired result, with the icon on the right]

Comment: Share the CSS for us to help with this?

Comment: @CanO'Spam this was specifically labeled as `tailwind`. There probably is no CSS and for a question labeled with a framework should also not be necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrap both the title and the icon in a `div` with the class `flex`. This way they will be placed on the same line.

You can also add `justify-between` to move the icon to the right corner.

A great suggestion from Cornel Raiu in the comments about adding `items-center` to the mix, to vertically align both the title and the icon.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="card bg-neutral h-48 px-3 hover:bg-primary">
  <div class="flex justify-between">
    <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold text-white py-3">Project name</h2>
    <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M10 6H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h10a2 2 0 002-2v-4M14 4h6m0 0v6m0-6L10 14" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p class="text-left py-4 font-bold group-hover:bg-primary">Explaination of the project</p>
  <p class="text-left pb-4 font-bold">Tag, tag, tag</p>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe add `items-center` as well to have the icon and the text vertically centered on the same line

Comment: @CornelRaiu Thank you, mentioned in the answer and gave you credit.

Answer (score 8):

Solutions provided here are full of boilerplate code. Here is simple solution using **inline-flex** and **span**:

```
<p>
Today I spent most of the day researching ways to ...
<span class="inline-flex items-baseline">
    <img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="" class="self-center w-5 h-5 rounded-full mx-1" />
    <span>Kramer</span>
</span>
keeps telling me there is no way to make it work, that ...
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `items-center` along with `justify-between` class that will keep the icon completely verticle align to the heading.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="card bg-neutral h-48 px-3 hover:bg-primary">
  <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
    <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold text-dark py-3">Project name</h2>
    <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M10 6H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h10a2 2 0 002-2v-4M14 4h6m0 0v6m0-6L10 14" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p class="text-left py-4 font-bold group-hover:bg-primary">Explaination of the project</p>
  <p class="text-left pb-4 font-bold">Tag, tag, tag</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps .

```
 <div class="flex items-center">
          <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
            <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
          </svg>
          <p class="ml-4">
            Icons
            <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">Next to Text...!</code> file
          </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).